# Swift Remove Tab Bar Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, segue

The main navigation for my iOS 8 app is a tab bar with 3 tabs. I also have a login screen that is a UIViewController that should not have tabs at the bottom. I only ever access the login screen programmatically from the normal flow if I detect that a user is either not logged in, or has chosen to log out. I'm not sure how to remove the tabs from the screen when I show the login screen with the following code:

```
let loginView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifer("Login") as UIViewController
self.presentViewController(loginView, animate: true, completion: nil)
```

I have tried setting the `tabBar.hidden` property to `true` with no result. I have also tried modifying the storyboard to set "Bottom Bar" to "None" and have checked "Hide Bottom Bar on Push".

Comment: What is self here? Where are you presenting the view controller from?

Comment: I'm presenting the view controller from a table view that lives inside of the TabViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the login screen's behavior is different from the main screen. So you might want to create another ViewController for the Login screen.

> I have tried setting the tabBar.hidden property to true with no result.

Does it finish to load the tab bar? Call `hidden=YES` after `viewDidLoad` of your loginView.

**EDIT**

After you call `self.presentViewController(loginView, ...)`, the UITabBarController's view will be removed from UIWindow, and the loginView's view will be inserted to UIWindow's subview. So the tab bar is invisible now.

You can use View Debugging feature of XCode6 to understand the view hierarchy. You can use UIViewController's `recursiveDescription()` method too.

```
/* UIViewExtension.h */
@interface UIView(MyExtension)
- (NSString*)recursiveDescription; //This is hidden API so need the declaration.
@end


/* YourViewController.swift */
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    println(self.tabBarController?.view.superview?.recursiveDescription())
    // Here, the view of tabBarController is subview of UIWindow.
}

@IBAction func testButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true) { () -> Void in
        println(self.tabBarController?.view.superview?.recursiveDescription())
        println(loginView.view.superview?.superview?.recursiveDescription())
        //Now, TabBarController's view is not subView of UIWindow. 
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a separate ViewController for the Login screen that is not connected to the TabViewController through any segue on the storyboard. When I set `hidden=YES`, I get a nil value.

Comment: I have tried your situation in my Xcode, and edited my answer.